# Automatic display of long and short acronyms

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra, glossary

Before when I was using acronyms, I was handling the long and short acronym by using \acrlong{} and \acrshort{}. I'd like to know if there's a way that when you call up an acronym, it displays the whole acronym the first time and then just the acronym the other times.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [glossaries-extra](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra?lang=en).

```
\usepackage[acronym,nomain]{glossaries-extra}
\newacronym{CNN}{CNN}{Convolutional Neural Network}
\makeglossaries
```

Then you use `\gls{CNN}` in the text! You can use `\glsxtrshort{CNN}` and `\glsxtrlong{CNN}` to manually use short and long versions.

Print out your acronyms with `\printglossary[type=acronym]`. Remember to run `makeglossaries main` (you will be reminded).

[Overleaf has a nice guide](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Glossaries) on how to use this.